# How to change db connection dynamically

Tags: model, schema, database-connection, symfony-1.4

I use two db for my project . In config . yml file

```
all:
  master:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=livetloc'
      username: root
       password: console
client:
class: sfDoctrineDatabase
param:
  dsn: 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testloc'
  username: root
  password: console
```

Then i generated schema and model . Now i need to change the db connection dynamically . if i write a new code in my project , i need to test it on the testloc db . After that i will change it to liveloc db  . This project is used by four members . I am adding the new features to it ,four members using the the project at same time but i use the "testloc" db. Others are using  "Liveloc" db . What is the solution to change  the db for particular login particular user within single enviroinment ?

Answer (score 0):

I had that need in a previous project and this is how I solved it :

In your controller :

```
// we get the params in your databases.yml file for your data source "client"
$dbParams = sfContext::getInstance()->getDatabaseManager()->getDatabase('client');

$paramsArray = array(
    $dbParams->getParameter('dsn'), 
    $dbParams->getParameter('username'),
    $dbParams->getParameter('password'),
    'testloc'
);

// setting "false" avoids this new connection to replace your default one
$newConnection = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->openConnection($params, 'name_of_connection', false);

$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = $newConnection->fetchAll($query);
```

That is not so cool because it uses symfony context but that does the trick ;). In a test context I think that it's good.